# Connection reset by peer, due to node failure in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I am running a couple of ignite nodes and using SQL table to store data in memory. Now bases on the number of nodes in the system, I have to make some changes when any node goes down.

To detect node failure every node has registered a listener which recieves an event when one of the node goes down.

But when the listener tries to fetch data from the table which is 'replicated' on all nodes, (using a connection object created earlier) it throws the following error.

```
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.send(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:376)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinTcpIo.sendRequest(JdbcThinTcpIo.java:325)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:668)
```

This says that the connection is closed by the server. But since we expect the connection to be to the cache nodes and not a particular server, is this not handled by ignite internally so that it takes care that when the server which holds the connection goes down, the connection is reset to a different server.

Or is this to be handled by the programmer itself. If yes what is the recommended course of action on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Ignite "thin" clients do not have automatic reconnection feature. Ignite "thin" client connects to one (client or server) Ignite node and uses it to channel all requests and responses. If this node goes away, "thin" client fails.

Automatic reconnection is reserved for "thick" clients which create a fully-fledged client node which maintains connections inside cluster on its own and can recover after node failures.

See [Ignite Drivers docs](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver) for examples on configuration of both types of drivers. The gist of it, `jdbc:ignite:thin://` means "thin" client without reconnects, and `jdbc:ignite:cfg://` means "thick" client node driver which can reconnect automatically.